# Setting "api key" on polymer iron-ajax client

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, polymer, aws-api-gateway, iron-ajax

I am trying to set an api key on iron-ajax client in a polymer app to consume an API Gateway endpoint of Amazon Web Services. On the server side(API Gateway) I enabled a wildcard on cors, also enabled x-api-key as header and granted credentials.
When I run my client, I always get the same response in Chrome:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
>
> The network response is {"message": "Forbidden"}

I tried the following code, changing things in multiple ways, but I got nothing.

```
    <iron-ajax
      id="requestOpensource"
      url='https://myservice.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/development/myservice'
      method='GET'
      headers = "{{ajaxParams}}"
      handle-as="json"
      content-type="application/json"
      on-response="handleResponse"
      with-credentials="true"
      on-error="handleErrorResponse">
    </iron-ajax>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view1',
      properties: {
        response: {
          type: Object
        },
        apikey: {
          type: String,
          value: '12345'
        },
        ajaxParams: {
          type: String,
          computed: 'processParams(apikey)'
        },
        headers: {
          type: Object,
          computed: 'getHeaders(customHeader)'
        },
        customHeader: {
          value: '12345'
        }
      },
      getHeaders: function(customHeader) {
        return {'X-API-Key': customHeader}
      },
      processParams: function(apikey) {
        return {
          key: apikey
        }
      },
      ready: function () {
        debugger
        this.$.requestOpensource.headers['x-api-key'] = "12345"
        //this.$.requestOpensource.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
        this.$.requestOpensource.generateRequest()
      }
  </script>
```

Also I used chrome plugin to enable cors but it is not a good solution for my customers (and also I got same response). I believe the problem is not setting properly the data on headers. But I read multiple forums and I dont know what to do next.

Thanks a lot for your responses!

Comment: Check this discussion I guess it has what you are looking for: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=193738

Comment: I believe it is a known issue on API Gateway when your request is failed on auth checks. Currently, there is no workaround for this limitation. By the way, you mentioned you granted credentials. Did you mention your API required AWS Auth? I don't see you sign your request before sending out to API Gateway.

Comment: Finally I resolved this issue redeploying again my api gateway. Also, on the client side I needed to remove "oncredentials" param and setting on header param to allow Access Control. Many thanks for your responses your post were very valuable.